# How to pause and resume gradient taping in eager execution?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a task which looks like this:

```
# compute estimates from input
net_estimate = my_model(inputs)
# use this estimate to compute a target
target_estimate = lots_of_computations(net_estimate)
# compute loss
loss = compute_loss(net_estimate, target_estimate)
```

(For some context, this is for a reinforcement learning task, for which the resulting state — and the reward — depends on the action taken by the network.)

The problem is that I do not want (indeed cannot) to compute the gradient of `lots_of_computations`. Ideally I would like to pause and resume gradient taping

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  net_estimate = my_model(inputs)
# target_estimate should be considered a constant
target_estimate = lots_of_computations(net_estimate)
with tape.resume():
  loss = compute_loss(net_estimate, target_estimate)
tape.gradient(loss, my_model.params)
```

But [`GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) does not seem to offer something similar to that. Is there a way to achieve this in eager mode? My current workaround is to compute `net_estimate` twice, but that is clearly suboptimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tf.GradientTape.stop_recording`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.9/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#stop_recording) is probably what you're looking for.

It was introduced recently (after TensorFlow 1.8), so at the moment you'll need to use TensorFlow 1.9.0's release candidate for this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Glad to see the developers anticipated that need. Can't wait for TF1.9!

Comment: There is now a nice documentation on how to use gradient tape in general and stop_recording in particular: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape